# Substr using with in a function

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

A function that's returning (character varying, integer, text) and the text field returning different strings with in them. How to display a substring of one string with in that text returning variable
[image]

Comment: an_format_name_f( ) functions works perfectly fine without using substr.

Comment: How to display a substring from one of the string in that returning text field is the main concern

Answer (score 1):

We can't use substr() function within a function, but possible solution is

```
an_format_name_f(an.soc_code,an.animals_key,'[anim_name] ' ) |+| substr(an.anim_ident,1,3) |+| an_format_name_f(an.soc_code,an.animals_key,'[horn] [colour]') end as anim_name_sire_cert
```